# Trouble passing props down to components, specifically two levels down - React Router, Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having trouble passing props down to different components when using react-router and trying to get props two levels down.

I have my main app.js where I'm immediately routing to my SplashPage component, then in SplashPage, I have my Authentication component called in the JSX (not via routing, just  with some props).

The trouble is, my Auth component needs props from app.js, but since I'm referencing it in my SplashPage component, those props aren't being passed properly, resulting in a console error telling me that various functions it's trying to use don't exist (Warning: ___ is not a function)

Here's what my app.js JSX looks like. Right now I'm trying to pass props into SplashPage so I can also pass them from there to Auth, but no luck so far!

```
<Router history={BrowserHistory}>
    <Switch>
         <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => ( <SplashPage {...props} isAuth={this.setIsAuth} authClasses={this.state.authPageClasses} />)} />
         <Route path='/auth' render={(props) => ( <Auth {...props} isAuth={this.setIsAuth} authClasses={this.state.authPageClasses} />)} />
        <Route path='/packingList' render={(props) => ( <PackingList {...props} isAuth={this.state.isAuth} email={this.state.email} user={this.state.user} name={this.state.name} />)} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

SplashPage component JSX:

```
<section className="splashPage">
     <div className={this.state.topWallClasses}>
         <h1>PackTracker</h1>
         <button onClick={this.enterSite}>start tracking!</button>
         <div className="overhang">
             <img src="public/assets/backpackRed.png" alt=""/>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div className={this.state.bottomWallClasses}></div>
     <Auth isAuth={this.setIsAuth} authClasses={this.state.authPageClasses} />
 </section>
```

Auth component JSX:

```
<Router history={BrowserHistory}>
     <Switch>
         <div>
             <Route path='/packingList' component={PackingList}/>
             <section className={this.props.authClasses}>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="" className="signup" onClick={this.formToShow}>Sign Up</a></li>
                     <li><a href="" className="login" onClick={this.formToShow}>Log In</a></li>
                 </ul>
                 {loginForm}
             </section>
         </div>
     </Switch>
</Router>
```

As it is, the SplashPage component appears, and the Auth component appears, but I can't actually log in because I need to access functions and state in app.js.

Additionally, once I get that working, I then want to be able to route to a different component from Auth via JS, using something like:

```
this.history.push("/packingList")
```

No idea how I'd be passing props there either, but time will tell! ha

Hope I explained that well! Starts to get a bit hard for me to explain when there's multiple components involved. I can offer more info if not. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, I think it might just be how you are trying to pass down your props to the 2nd level. For example, in your SplashPage Auth component: `<Auth isAuth={this.setIsAuth} authClasses={this.state.authPageClasses} />` should look like `<Auth isAuth={props.isAuth} authClasses={props.authClasses} />` You want to refer to these by the prop name you've given it in the component that passed it down (you called is "isAuth" in App.js). Either props.isAuth (if it's a functional component) or this.props.isAuth (if it's a class)

Comment: I dont see you pass props to Auth from SplashPage. maybe that is why?

Comment: As to the 2nd part: you can access `this.history` by using the [https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter](withRouter higher-order component). You'd want to do something like `export default withRouter(App);`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not passing the props through.

In your "SplashPage Component JSX":

```
<section className="splashPage">
   <div className={this.state.topWallClasses}>
       <h1>PackTracker</h1>
       <button onClick={this.enterSite}>start tracking!</button>
       <div className="overhang">
         <img src="public/assets/backpackRed.png" alt=""/>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div className={this.state.bottomWallClasses}></div>
   <Auth isAuth={this.setIsAuth} authClasses={this.state.authPageClasses} />
 </section>
```

Note the `Auth` component:

```
<Auth isAuth={this.setIsAuth} authClasses={this.state.authPageClasses} />
```

I don't see you passing any `props` through..  perhaps try something similar to your main `Router` rendering:

```
<Auth {...this.props} isAuth={this.setIsAuth} authClasses={this.state.authPageClasses} />
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion! However, I made that change in my code and there's no change :(

Comment: Yeah this isn't a solution, just a hint in the right direction.  Think about what you're passing to `<Auth>` - what are the _values_ of these props?

Comment: What does your `Auth` component do with `setIsAuth`?  Where is the implementation for `setIsAuth` ?

Comment: setIsAuth changes some state in app.js, then in my PackingList component, I do things based on that state